# RedisSessionStateProvider with ProtoBuf serialization causing errors

Tags: c#, redis, protobuf-net, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to get protobuf serialization working with the RedisSessionStateProvider.  I have specified the redisSerializerType as a custom class which implements Microsoft.Web.Redis.ISerializer - here is the deserialization code:

```
    public object Deserialize(byte[] data)
    {
        return DeserializeDirect(data);
    }

    private object DeserializeDirect(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<object>(memoryStream);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

As I need to implement Microsoft.Web.Redis.ISerializer the signature for deserialize uses a return type of object and there is no way to pass in the actual type being returned.  So when DeserializeDirect tries to use the Protobuf.Serializer to deserialize it (as expected) says "Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.Object".  I am using a web app with .NET framework 4.6.1 and I was hoping somebody could point out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, protobuf-net *really* wants to know the exact type. You can, however, cheat using `DynamicType`. This tells protobuf-net to include additional type metadata - something it doesn't usually include.

Note that this can make you code brittle - it may fail if the type changes in you code!

I will be implementing `Any` soon (as part of 2.3.0), which is another option here.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // the actual object we care about
    object obj = new Foo { X = 1 };

    // serialize and deserialize via stub
    var stub = new Stub { Data = obj };
    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(stub);
    // prove it worked
    Console.WriteLine(clone.Data);
    // prove it is a different instance
    Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(obj, clone.Data));
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int X { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"X={X}";
}

[ProtoContract]
public sealed class Stub
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, this is exactly what I needed!